# How to customise \title to include a shadow effect on a paper?

Tags: line-breaking, titles, text-decorations, shadows

The `shadowtext` package allows you to use the command `\shadowtext` to create a shadow behind the letters like so

```
\documentclass{paper}

\usepackage{shadowtext}

\title{\shadowtext{Title}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

If, however, I want to break the title into two lines or more I can't use

```
\documentclass{paper}

\usepackage{shadowtext}

\title{\shadowtext{Very long Title \\ is very long}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Supposing I want to decide where to break it and not leave this decision to the machine.

`shadowtext` does not understand the line breaking command `\\` and so I have to write

```
\documentclass{paper}

\usepackage{shadowtext}

\title{\shadowtext{Very long Title} \\ \shadowtext{is very long}}

\begin{document} 
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to customise `\title` in order to just call `\title{Very long title \\ is very long}` and have a shadow text automatically?

Answer (score 2):

[`shadowtext`](http://ctan.org/pkg/shadowtext) inserts the background as a picture, so you can use any regular stacking methods to put something one above the other. Below I use `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{paper}

\usepackage{shadowtext}

\title{\shadowtext{\begin{tabular}{c} top \\ bottom \end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Of course, you can adjust the alignment to suit your needs.

<sub>Depending on your setup, there may be no need for using `\title` and `\maketitle`. In this case, you could use a `\begin{center} \shadowtext{top} \\ \shadowtext{bottom} \end{center}` setup.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Shadowing text can also be emulated at the font level by overlapping the same text onto itself in a different colour and with a slight offset.

[image: shadow with kerning and overlap]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{red!3}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontface\fa{Noto Serif}[Scale=2,Colour=AFDFD0]
\newfontface\fb{Noto Serif}[Scale=2,Colour=AF4A64]%bg

\newcommand\sometext{The Art of Kerning}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Kern and overlap:

\begin{center}
{\fb The Art of Kerning\kern-0.52pt\raisebox{-0.52pt}{\llap{\fa The Art of Kerning}}}
\end{center}


Tikz version, xshift and yshift:

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,-1) {\fb\sometext};
\node at (0,-1) [xshift=-0.54pt,
    yshift=-0.54pt,]{\fa\sometext};
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


Tikz, opacity background and white foreground:
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[scale=2,opacity=0.8,color=red] at (0.03,-0.04){\sometext} ;  
\node at (0,0) [scale=2,color=white]{\sometext};
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Kerning and overlapping two text strings only works if they both start at the same place.

Long text in a Tikz node can be line-wrapped with the `text width=` option, e,g, set to 4cm:

[image: long lines in Tikz]